# Why ImportError: No module named 'cv2' error come only for python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

for python2, open cv library successfully added. But while i choose python3 i can't. 
Default version is python3.5. Here i have attached the screenshot.

> ImportError: No module named 'cv2'

[image]

Comment: How have you installed the OpenCV library. It seems that it has been installed for Python2 and not Python3.

Comment: i used this command to install - 'sudo apt-get install python-opencv' . Now i changed the python version to 3

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be installation problem. The python interpreter should the path of all libraries that are available for use. By default, the directory containing the python interpreter should be containing all the libraries that are compatible with that version. You should try this command `which python3` to know the python3 installation path and see if the cv2 library installed there or not. You need to refer the how python interpreter finds the third part libraries.